# How to hide scroll bar indicator on TextInput in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I would like to hide or remove the scroll bar indicator on the TextInput component.I enabled **multiline** props to **true** then I set the props **scrollEnabled** to **false**.But in my component still showing scroll indicator. I am using the following code. Please help me how to solve this issue.

```
<TextInput
        multiline={true}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          height:50,
          fontSize: 20,
          color: '#ffff',
          fontFamily: 'medium'
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Is your project using Android? `scrollEnabled` props only work on [IOS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#scrollenabled).

Comment: I tried this code in react native web

Comment: I would recommend you using emulator or real phone, because there usually have some different between emulator and web,  in react native web have choose could change to android or ios, I've tried scrollEnabled={false} in ios,seems let single line but if true may appear a little indicator. Android seems doesn't have this setting

Comment: was there a resolution on this? i'm trying to do the same right now

Answer (score 0):

As of the end of 2023, there is no attribute in order to do not show the `scroll indicator` in `TextInput` component in React Native.

In this case, the solution I came up with, is pretty simple, but requires `ScrollView` component and some additional styling.

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'transparent' }}>
  <ScrollView
    style={{
     flex: 1,
     borderWidth: 1,
     borderColor: 'transparent',
     paddingHorizontal: 5,
     borderRadius: 8,
    }}
   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} // Hide the scroll indicator
  >
  <TextInput
   value={content}
   onChangeText={setContent}
   multiline
   numberOfLines={50}
   style={{
     flex: 1,
     fontSize: 14,
   }}
  />
 </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Hope this answers your question, and helps everyone who encounters this problem.